# Have there been more books written about Napoleon Bonaparte than days have passed since his death?

Tags: history

Searching for [more books on Napoleon than days since his death](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=more+books+on+napoleon+than+days+since+his+death) on Google shows a few websites that make this claim. Note that Napoleon Bonaparte died roughly 200 years ago, or about 73.000 days ago.

The source most of those websites use is an essay called [Review of Books Written about Napoleon Bonaparte](https://www.ukessays.com/essays/history/books-written-about-napoleon-bonaparte-history-essay.php) which claims

> The last estimate for the number of books written on Napoleon was over 300,000 (J.D. Markham, 9)

I don't know what "J.D. Markham, 9" refers to. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._David_Markham), J. David Markham is an expert on Napoleon Bonaparte. Regardless of who he is though, I'd prefer to see some concrete evidence of this claim to believe it.

Another [website](https://claremontreviewofbooks.com/the-man-on-horseback/) says:

> Munro Price, quoting yet another biographer of Napoleon, claims there have been “[w]ell over 200,000 books…written about him since his death.”

I wasn't able to find out where Munro Price quoted this "other biographer of Napoleon", let alone who this "other biographer of Napoleon" is.

I've seen mentioned in [some places](https://historum.com/threads/is-it-true-that-napoleon-has-more-books-written-about-him-than-any-other-prominent-figure-in-history.187448/) that Amazon references 40.000 books on Napoleon but 1) not all of those books are about Napoleon *Bonaparte*, and 2) 40.000 is far from 300.000 and fairly far from 73.000 as well.

In the end, I didn't manage to find any primary source, or any explanation of the methodology of those primary sources.

So, have there been more books written about Napoleon Bonaparte than days have passed since his death? Are there more than 300.000 books on Napoleon Bonaparte?

Comment: Welcome to Skeptics! Sorry for the downvotes, your question shares some characteristics of typical spam (don't ask why). They'll be reversed shortly.

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks for the explanation; I was quite surprised by seeing -3 literally seconds after posting.

Comment: Some context: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307585/295232 - bottom line: we *need* this line of protection to keep the sites free from spam, and cases like your question are rare and usually quickly fixed.

Comment: According to [Andrew Roberts](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/307215/napoleon-by-andrew-roberts/), it's specifically  *titles* that contain "Napoleon". (However, I don't trust him as a source for an answer; people who aren't experts in corpus research tend to make mistakes.)

Comment: The 9 is probably footnote #9, which would tell you the book name and page. But the footnotes were cut out. Since it's a sample student essay, you could probably find that quote as easily as they did.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**>70.000 books *and articles* about the general historic vicinity of Napoleon, in 1908.**

**... and [napoleon.org says 'yes'](http://bibliotheque-martial-lapeyre.napoleon.org/a-decouvrir-discover.aspx?lg=en-GB)**

There is an [article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1862287.pdf) (*"Historical Investigation and the Commercial History of the Napoleonic Era", 1914, W.E.Lingelbach*) that quotes *"Kircheisen, Bibliographie du Temps de Napoleon (Paris, I908), p. viii."* as saying

> "[...] assured his readers that he had over  70,000 independent
> titles, and, if translations and editions were considered, over
> 200,000[...]"

this quote is in the context of

> "[...] military, diplomatic, and political history of the Napoleonic
> era [...]  Literally thousands of volumes-the  latest bibliography on
> Napoleonic history speaks of 200,000 titles-  have been written on
> some phase or other of the history of this  period"

Yet the [book itself](https://numelyo.bm-lyon.fr/f_view/BML:BML_00GOO0100137001104319343) says at the quoted spot:

> Je possède maintenant plus de 70000 titres d'ouvrages et d'articles dans ma bibliographie [...]

So the

> 'books written about Napoleon Bonaparte'

from the Q needs to be interpreted as

> 'books **and articles** written about the general historic vicinity of Napoleon Bonaparte', i.e. writings that somehow help the reader understand the Napoleonic times

, which is not unreasonable for a historical examination - we cannot expect pure biographies to exist in those numbers.

Why they count translations and editions to arrive at the 200.000 unmber is opaque to me, though.

note Kircheisen, on the same page says that in that bibliography he counts 8000 articles and books as 'the most important and most serious'

Comment: I found the book you refer to : https://numelyo.bm-lyon.fr/f_view/BML:BML_00GOO0100137001104319343 .
On said page, it refers to any kind of article or book that mentions Napoleon, not just books. So it is not a good source for the claim that there are >70k **books** about Napoleon

Comment: @Hector thank you! - changed my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From @Hector's link, Kircheisen writes that he collected all books/articles referencing events from the beginning of the French Revolution (1789) to the end of the Restoration (which could be either 1815 or 1830), and that he then filtered those books/articles to keep only those about Napoleon. It's not clear that 70.000 refers to the books before or after this filtering. If it's before the filtering, then I suspect that it also includes a lot of items about the French Revolution, most of which have nothing to do with Napoleon.

Comment: Also, as I said, those 70.000 books could include books/articles about the 2nd Restoration (1815-1830), when Napoleon was either in exile or dead. Still, some of those books will be about the consequences of his actions, but I suspect that some others will be unrelated.

Comment: For some context: Napoleon was governing France from 1799 to 1814/1815. So Kircheisen collected books/articles from 10 years before he came to power, to 15 years after he was kicked out. Once again, some of those books will be relevant, others wont.

Comment: @DD4 you are right, i will adapt the answer